# Поиск всех совпадений регулярному выражению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть код сайта и я хотел бы найти ссылки в в этом коде по таким критериям:
Начало `<td class="player"><a href="/player/` а конец " и что между ними надо найти, таких результатов будет 10 и каждый надо сохранить, как такое сделать? Я нашел только как 1 сохранить..
Пример HTML кода(очень огромный):

```
b'b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" id="metaViewport">\n    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1004164229">\n    <meta property="fb:pages" content="249997999009">\n    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1460388157605817">\n    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="DcypRFLQvgYQL5Acx7feoGWbblSsmKv6HpPI7mM_1uw">\n    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">\n    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/static/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">\n    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/static/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">\n    <link rel="manifest" href="/img/static/favicon/manifest.json">\n    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/img/static/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">\n    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">\n    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Oswald:700&amp;amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.15.0/raven.min.js"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/hltv-csstheme.js?hash=df73d0c197fafcc78aa1a2dd4f4737c7" data-day-css="b3f4be4a65cf62bb5b98ff6fb57100c9" data-night-css="cb563c7041bc4d4ca98a8d616dc7524a"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/hltv.js?hash=1230be3cc0ee223e10b6a4f52c7bd2ec"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://notification-secure.hltv.org/hltvNotification.js?v2" async="async"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://scorebot-secure.hltv.org/scorebotClientApi.js?v5" async="async"></script>\n    <title>spray&apos;n&apos;pray vs. Impossible at Headshot Cup #2 | HLTV.org</title>\n    <link href="/rss/news" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">\n    <meta name="description" content="Complete overview of the spray&apos;n&apos;pray vs. Impossible matchup  at Headshot Cup #2!">\n    <meta property="og:title" content="HLTV.org - The home of competitive Counter-Strike">\n    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hltv.org/img/static/openGraphHltvLogo.png">\n    <meta property="og:site_name" content="HLTV.org">\n  </head>\n  <body class="preload colsCustom1101" data-livescore-server-url="https://scorebot-secure.hltv.org">\n    <div class="navbar">\n      <div class="navcon"><a href="/" class="small-logo"><img alt="HLTV.org" src="/img/static/TopSmallLogo2x.png" class="small-logo-img"></a><a href="/" class="navnews">News</a><a href="/matches" class="navmatches">Matches</a><a href="/results" class="navresults">Results</a><a href="/events" class="navevents">Events</a>\n        <div class="navburger navburger1"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>\n        <div class="navbreakline1"></div>\n<a href="/stats" class="navstats">Stats</a><a href="/galleries" class="navgalleries">Galleries</a><a href="/ranking/teams" class="navranking smartphone-only">Rankings</a><a href="/forums" class="navforums">Forums</a>\n        <div class="navburger navburger2"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>\n        <div class="navbreakline2"></div>\n        <div class="navsearch search-typeahead">\n          <form action="/search?term="><input type="text" class="navsearchinput" name="query" data-topbar-search-url="/search?term=" placeholder="Search...">\n            <div class="search-submit-hidden"><input type="submit" tabIndex="-1"></div>\n          </form>\n          <div class="navsearchborder"></div>\n<span class="navsearchicon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></div>\n        <div class="navborder"></div>\n        <div class="navsignin" data-overlay-popup-button="" data-overlay-popup-content="overlay-popup-1462440830">Sign in</div>\n        <div class="hidden">\n          <div class="fixed-overlay-popup-content-con" id="overlay-popup-1462440830">\n            <div class="fixed-overlay-popup-content">\n              <div class="login-dialog standard-box" data-login-url="/login">\n                <div class="logo"><img alt="HLTV.org" src="/img/static/TopSmallLogo2x.png" height="46px"></div>\n                <form><input type="text" name="username" class="loginInput" required="required" placeholder="Username"><input type="password" name="password" class="loginInput" required="required" placeholder="Password">\n                  <div class="login-elm clearfix"><span class="remember-me left"><input type="checkbox" name="autologin" class="loginCheckbox" checked="checked"> Remember me</span><span class="forgot-link right" data-overlay-popup-content="overlay-popup-992863196">Forgot password</span></div>\n                  <div class="login-error"></div>\n<button type="submit" class="login-button button" name="login">Login</button></form>\n                <hr class="login-elm">\n<a href="/signup" class="signup-button button">Sign up</a></div>\n            </div>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="hidden">\n          <div class="fixed-overlay-popup-content-con" id="overlay-popup-992863196">\n            <div class="fixed-overlay-popup-content">\n              <div class="forgot-password-dialog standard-box">\n                <div>\n                  <div class="logo"><img alt="HLTV.org" src="/img/static/TopSmallLogo2x.png" height="46px"></div>\n                  <div id="forgot-password-username"><input type="text" name="username" class="loginInput" required="required" placeholder="Username"><span class="validation-error hidden"><i class=" fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="message"></span></span></div>\n                </div>\n                <div>\n                  <div class="g-recaptcha" id="forgot-password-recaptcha"></div>\n<button type="button" class="recover-button button" data-forgot-password-location="/forgotpassword">Recover</button>\n                  <hr class="login-elm">\n<button type="button" class="back-button button" data-overlay-popup-button="" data-overlay-popup-content="overlay-popup-1462440830">Back</button></div>\n              </div>\n            </div>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="navborder"></div>\n        <div class="navdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>\n          <div class="arrow"></div>\n          <div class="arrow2"></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="navpopup" id="popupsettings">\n          <div class="nav-popup-header">Settings</div>\n          <div class="nav-popup-elm"><span>Toggle nightmode</span><span class="right"><span class="toggleUserTheme userTheme-night" data-url="/profile/settings/changetheme?theme=night">On</span><span> / </span><span class="toggleUserTheme userTheme-day selected" data-url="/profile/settings/changetheme?theme=day">off</span></span></div>\n          <div class="nav-popup-elm"><span>Timezone</span><span class="right">\n              <form action=""><select class="timezoneSelector" data-timezone-update-on-select="1" id="timezoneSelector" name="timezone"></select></form>\n            </span></div>\n          <div class="nav-popup-elm desktop-mode-con"><span>Force desktop mode</span><span class="right"><span class="toggleDesktopMode desktopModeOn">On</span><span> / </span><span class="toggleDesktopMode desktopModeOff">off</span></span></div>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n    <div class="bgPadding">\n      <div class="widthControl">\n        <div class="logoCon"><a href="/">\n            <div class="hltv-logo-container"></div>\n          </a>\n          <div class="" id="i0_middle"></div>\n          <div class="" id="i0_right"></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="colCon">\n          <div class="contentCol">\n            <div class="match-page">\n              <div class="standard-box teamsBox">\n                <div class="team"><img alt="Ukraine" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/300x200/UA.png" class="team1 " title="Ukraine">\n                  <div class="team1-gradient"><a href="/team/7264/spraynpray"><img alt="spray&apos;n&apos;pray" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7264" class="logo" title="spray&apos;n&apos;pray">\n                      <div class="teamName">spray&apos;n&apos;pray</div>\n                    </a></div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="timeAndEvent">\n                  <div class="time" data-time-format="HH:mm" data-unix="1496768400000">19:00</div>\n                  <div class="date" data-time-format="do &apos;of&apos; MMMM Y" data-unix="1496768400000">6th of June 2017</div>\n                  <div class="event text-ellipsis"><a href="/events/2886/headshot-cup-2" title="Headshot Cup #2">Headshot Cup #2</a></div>\n                  <div class="text dummy-spacer">\xc2\xa0</div>\n                  <div class="countdown" data-time-countdown="LIVE" data-unix="1496768400000">1h : 27m : 36s</div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="team"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/300x200/RU.png" class="team2 " title="Russia">\n                  <div class="team2-gradient"><a href="/team/7835/impossible"><img alt="Impossible" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7835" class="logo" title="Impossible">\n                      <div class="teamName">Impossible</div>\n                    </a></div>\n                </div>\n              </div>\n              <div class="section-spacer"></div>\n              <div class="flexbox fix-half-width-margin maps">\n                <div class="half-width "><span class="headline">Maps</span>\n                  <div class="standard-box veto-box">\n                    <div class="padding preformatted-text">Best of 3\n\n* Semi-final</div>\n                  </div>\n                  <div class="flexbox-column">\n                    <div class="mapholder">\n                      <div class="spacing ">\n                        <div class="map-name-holder"><img src="/img/static/maps/tba.png" class="minimap">\n                          <div class="mapname">TBA</div>\n                        </div>\n                      </div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="mapholder">\n                      <div class="spacing ">\n                        <div class="map-name-holder"><img src="/img/static/maps/tba.png" class="minimap">\n                          <div class="mapname">TBA</div>\n                        </div>\n                      </div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="mapholder">\n                      <div class="spacing optional">\n                        <div class="map-name-holder"><img src="/img/static/maps/tba.png" class="minimap">\n                          <div class="mapname">TBA</div>\n                        </div>\n                      </div>\n                    </div>\n                  </div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="half-width"><span class="headline">Watch</span>\n                  <div class="streams">\n                    <div class="stream-box " data-stream-embed="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=binarydragons_4"><span class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="stream-flag flag" title="Russia">Binary Dragons 4</span><span class="viewers left-right-padding">0</span></div>\n                  </div>\n                </div>\n              </div>\n              <div class="section-spacer"></div>\n              <div class="video-container hidden">\n                <div class="standard-box videoWrapper"></div>\n                <div class="section-spacer"></div>\n              </div>\n              <div class="flexbox fix-half-width-margin">\n                <div class="three-quarter-width"><span class="headline">Betting</span>\n                  <div class="betting standard-box padding">\n                    <table class="table">\n                      <tr class="">\n                        <td class="provider-cell"></td>\n                        <td class="team-cell">spray&apos;n&apos;pray</td>\n                        <td class="team-cell"></td>\n                        <td class="team-cell">Impossible</td>\n                      </tr>\n                      <tr class="">\n                        <td class=""><a href="http://egbaffiliates.com/track?p=tables&amp;aff_id=52"><img src="https://static.hltv.org/images/egb.png" class="betting-logo"></a></td>\n                        <td class="odds-cell border-left"><a href="http://egbaffiliates.com/track?p=play/simple_bets&amp;aff_id=52&amp;anchor=282890">1.47</a></td>\n                        <td class="odds-cell border-left"><a href="http://egbaffiliates.com/track?p=play/simple_bets&amp;aff_id=52&amp;anchor=282890">-</a></td>\n                        <td class="odds-cell border-left"><a href="http://egbaffiliates.com/track?p=play/simple_bets&amp;aff_id=52&amp;anchor=282890">2.41</a></td>\n                      </tr>\n                      <tr class="">\n                        <td class="">\n                  </div>\n                </div>\n                <div class="quarter-width"><span class="headline">Pick a winner</span>\n                  <div class="standard-box pick-a-winner">\n                    <div class="flexbox-column">\n                      <div class="pick-a-winner-team team1 canvote" data-pick-a-winner-team="1" data-pick-a-winner-url="/matches/2311385/pickawinner">\n                        <div class="pick-a-winner-team-name">spray&apos;n&apos;pray</div>\n                        <div class="percentage">65.8%</div>\n                        <div class="pick-a-winner-team-bg"><img alt="spray&apos;n&apos;pray" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7264" class="logo" title="spray&apos;n&apos;pray"></div>\n                      </div>\n                      <div class="pick-a-winner-team team2 canvote" data-pick-a-winner-team="2" data-pick-a-winner-url="/matches/2311385/pickawinner">\n                        <div class="pick-a-winner-team-name">Impossible</div>\n                        <div class="percentage">34.2%</div>\n                        <div class="pick-a-winner-team-2-bg"><img alt="Impossible" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7835" class="logo" title="Impossible"></div>\n                      </div>\n                    </div>\n                  </div>\n                </div>\n              </div>\n              <div class="section-spacer"></div>\n              <div class="csgofastbetting"><iframe id="hltvBetWidget" src="https://hltv.gainskins.com/w3/match/hid/2311385/7264/7835/0cca454036cc79ac81bf35d3e6e1aa87?http://www.hltv.org/team1Name=spray%27n%27pray&amp;http://www.hltv.org/team2Name=Impossible&amp;http://www.hltv.org/startsAt=2017-06-06+19%3A00%3A00&amp;http://www.hltv.org/matchUrl=%2Fmatches%2F2311385%2Fspraynpray-vs-impossible-headshot-cup-2&amp;initialLoad=1&amp;autoResize=1" width="100%" height="347px" frameborder="none"></iframe></div>\n              <div class="section-spacer"></div>\n              <div class="rek gtSmartphone-only" id="matchpage_1"></div>\n              <div class="lineups"><span class="headline">Lineups</span>\n                <div class="">\n                  <div class="lineup standard-box">\n                    <div class="box-headline flex-align-center"><img alt="spray&apos;n&apos;pray" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7264" class="logo" title="spray&apos;n&apos;pray"><a href="/team/7264/spraynpray">spray&apos;n&apos;pray</a></div>\n                    <div class="players">\n                      <table class="table">\n                        <tr>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/13899/la3euka">\n                              <div><img alt="Vladimir &apos;la3euka&apos; Shurygin" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/blankplayer.svg" class="player-photo" title="Vladimir &apos;la3euka&apos; Shurygin"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/8368/jmqa">\n                              <div><img alt="Savelii &apos;jmqa&apos; Bragin" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/8368/400.jpeg?v=5" class="player-photo" title="Savelii &apos;jmqa&apos; Bragin"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/9349/F1L1N">\n                              <div><img alt="Ivan &apos;F1L1N&apos; Semenets" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/9349/400.jpeg?v=2" class="player-photo" title="Ivan &apos;F1L1N&apos; Semenets"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/7609/Tresh1k">\n                              <div><img alt="Bogdan &apos;Tresh1k&apos; Nakonechniy" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/7609/400.jpeg?v=2" class="player-photo" title="Bogdan &apos;Tresh1k&apos; Nakonechniy"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/1866/Shara">\n                              <div><img alt="Oleksandr &apos;Shara&apos; Hordieyev" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/1866/400.jpeg?v=2" class="player-photo" title="Oleksandr &apos;Shara&apos; Hordieyev"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                        </tr>\n                        <tr>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/13899/la3euka">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">la3euka</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/8368/jmqa">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">jmqa</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/9349/F1L1N">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Ukraine" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/UA.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Ukraine">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">F1L1N</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/7609/Tresh1k">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Ukraine" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/UA.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Ukraine">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">Tresh1k</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/1866/Shara">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Ukraine" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/UA.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Ukraine">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">Shara</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                        </tr>\n                      </table>\n                    </div>\n                  </div>\n                  <div class="lineup standard-box">\n                    <div class="box-headline flex-align-center"><img alt="Impossible" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7835" class="logo" title="Impossible"><a href="/team/7835/impossible">Impossible</a></div>\n                    <div class="players">\n                      <table class="table">\n                        <tr>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/8120/PLAZ">\n                              <div><img alt="Kiril &apos;PLAZ&apos; Sidorov" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/8120/400.jpeg?v=1" class="player-photo" title="Kiril &apos;PLAZ&apos; Sidorov"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/9082/krecker">\n                              <div><img alt="Petr &apos;krecker&apos; Stepanov" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/9082/400.jpeg?v=1" class="player-photo" title="Petr &apos;krecker&apos; Stepanov"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/7404/insom">\n                              <div><img alt="Igor &apos;insom&apos; Cherkasov" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/7404/400.jpeg?v=1" class="player-photo" title="Igor &apos;insom&apos; Cherkasov"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/12015/AKIMOV">\n                              <div><img alt="Erik &apos;AKIMOV&apos; Akimov" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/blankplayer.svg" class="player-photo" title="Erik &apos;AKIMOV&apos; Akimov"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/12016/svyat">\n                              <div><img alt="Svyatoslav &apos;svyat&apos; Dovbakh" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/blankplayer.svg" class="player-photo" title="Svyatoslav &apos;svyat&apos; Dovbakh"></div>\n                            </a></td>\n                        </tr>\n                        <tr>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/8120/PLAZ">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">PLAZ</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/9082/krecker">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">krecker</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/7404/insom">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">insom</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/12015/AKIMOV">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n                                <div class="text-ellipsis">AKIMOV</div>\n                              </div>\n                            </a></td>\n                          <td class="player"><a href="/player/12016/svyat">\n                              <div class="flagAlign"><img alt="Russia" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/bigflags/30x20/RU.gif" class="flag gtSmartphone-only" title="Russia">\n          '
```

Comment: Используйте `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Я так понял эта штука делает из нечитабельного кода в читабельный? Но мне это не нужно..

Comment: BeautifulSoup - это HTML-парсер. То, что вам нужно.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример с куском html и какие данные из него нужно вытащить. Для парсинга html нужно использовать html парсер, регулярки не лучший инструмент для парсинга xml/html

Comment: Пример добавил.

Comment: Ей богу, столько вопросов по регуляркам... Ну почитайте хоть немного о регулярных выражениях. Ну самим же будет полезно разобраться что и как

Comment: Можно ссылку на более-менее понятное объяснение, что означает например * после ([0-9/]) и почему после 9 идет /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно вам помогут методы [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) или `re.finditer?`
`findall` довольно легко использовать:

```
for i in re.findall('<td class="player"><a href="/player/([A-Za-z0-9/]*)"' ,text):
    print(i)
```

и он найдёт как раз пользователей, которые вам нужны:

```
13899/la3euka
8368/jmqa
9349/F1L1N
7609/Tresh1k
1866/Shara
```

Такде заметьте, что `re.findall` принимает переменную типа `str`, а вы получаете вашу html-страницу как набор байт.

Чтобы получить множество всех значений иожно привести сначала список к множеству, а потом обратно к списку:

```
find = re.findall('<td class="player"><a href="/player/([A-Za-z0-9/]*)"' ,text)
print(list(set(find)))
```

Comment: Возможно, но как ими воспользоватся я не понял, у меня выходит ошибка TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas что гугл переводчик говорит?

Comment: Уже понял что str() надо было добавить, но он начинает правильно но не останавливается

Comment: А как убрать повторения? Там идут ссылки на фото и на сам профиль вроде, должно выдать 10 пользователей, а выдает 20

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas Используйте `set(content)`

Comment: Ну set сделал из результат что-то непонятное, да еще и каждую букву в массив, мне бы избавится от такой штуки, чтобы небыло одинаковых строк:
13899/la3euka
8368/jmqa
9349/F1L1N
7609/Tresh1k
1866/Shara
13899/la3euka
8368/jmqa
9349/F1L1N
7609/Tresh1k
1866/Shara
8120/PLAZ
9082/krecker
7404/insom
12015/AKIMOV
12016/svyat
8120/PLAZ
9082/krecker
7404/insom
12015/AKIMOV
12016/svyat

Comment: Как вы делали `set() ` ?

Comment: Вышла еще более странная хрень, должно было выдать в 1 строке 13899/la3euka а выдает 1uk/38le9a да еще и каждую букву в массиве

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas привидите код в результате которого получилось такое. Тут плохо с ясновидящими.

Comment: 'for i in re.findall('<td class="player"><a href="/player/([A-Za-z0-9/]*)"' , str(text)):
    print(set(i))'

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas Так правильно. Вы делаете цикл. В цикле у вас `i` --очередной результат. То есть строка. И вы из этой одной строки пытаетесь сделать множество. Оно и будет множеством символов. А вам надо сделать множество из всех строк. Посмотрите в ответ

Comment: Да, это то что мне надо, спасибо

Comment: Зачем приводить результат к `set`, потом к `list`? По `set`'у отлично можно итерироваться

Comment: А как задать чтобы искал числа простые, с точкой и с %? Я сделал ([0-9/])* мне выдает только последнее число где нет ни точки ни %

Answer (score 4):

Еще один вариант:

```
In [43]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [44]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

In [46]: links = set(s.find('a').get('href')
                     for s in soup.find_all('td', {'class':['player']}))

In [47]: links
Out[47]:
{'/player/12015/AKIMOV',
 '/player/12016/svyat',
 '/player/13899/la3euka',
 '/player/1866/Shara',
 '/player/7404/insom',
 '/player/7609/Tresh1k',
 '/player/8120/PLAZ',
 '/player/8368/jmqa',
 '/player/9082/krecker',
 '/player/9349/F1L1N'}
```

Comment: Внутри set() можно убрать квадратные скобки списка :)

Comment: @gil9red, действительно, спасибо ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Парсить html регулярками не рекомендуется, поэтому предлагаю еще вариант, с использованием `BeautifulSoup`:

```
# Строка или байтовый массив с страницей html
html = ...

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

player_list = set()
for a in root.select('.player > a[href]'):
    player = a['href'].replace('/player/', '')
    player_list.add(player)

# Короткая запись
# player_list = set(a['href'].replace('/player/', '') for a in root.select('.player > a[href]'))

print(player_list)
```

Консоль:

```
{'9349/F1L1N', '7609/Tresh1k', '9082/krecker', '7404/insom', '1866/Shara', '13899/la3euka', '8120/PLAZ', '12015/AKIMOV', '12016/svyat', '8368/jmqa'}
```